# User.Identity.Name no longer retains username of current logged in user after creating new user in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, identity

I am pretty new to asp.net membership classes. Please forgivwe me for asking such a fundamental question. I did a brief search but have not found the answer and I'm running out of time.

I am making use of the LoginName, LogIn and CreateUSerWizard controls.

Everything works fine except when I create a new user. The Login Name immediately changes to the show the name of the new user I created. I store the User.Identity.Name in a Session("user") at log in so I thought I could change the contents of User.Identity.Name by setting it the value of the Session variable in the ActivateStep event of the CompleteWizard Step but User.Identity.Name is read only.

How do I change the content of User.Identity.Name or change the content of LogInName after Creating a new User?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the `CreateUserWizard` to create a new user, you'll need to set the [`LoginCreatedUser` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.createuserwizard.logincreateduser.aspx) to `false`.

Comment: Thanks Richard, It worked in less than 5 minutes of applying it. Gracias!